# Does facebook graph api block endpoint(page-id/block) only work for facebook pages? Not for Instagram pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, block, instagram-graph-api

Does facebook graph api block endpoint(page-id/block) only work for facebook pages? Not for Instagram pages? Nothing like that mentioned in docs and I use other apis to get posts and comments and it works for instagram as well. I tried block api and seems that it just works for facebook pages, not instagram pages. am I right?